# Comparing two list using lambda expression

Tags: c#

I want to get a list of string based in two lists lstJobs and lstPraudits. I want to get PlanId which is common in both list.

Here is my code-

```
List<string> result=reviewModel.lstJobs.Select(x=>x.planId.Contains(reviewModel.lstPraudits.Slect(y=>y.PlanId).toList()));
```

What I am doing wrong here. Code is giving error message.

Comment: A source of error messages may be miss spelled identifiers like `Slect` and `toList` unless you have defined these methods yourself.

Comment: you miss spelling of Select

Comment: What is the type of planId? Is it a collection? Also I see the spelling of Select is wrong in the inner query.

Comment: Be sure and mark the answer that you feel helped to solve your problem.

Comment: _"Code is giving error message"_ Next time also provide this error-message ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.Intersect`:

```
List<string> result = reviewModel.lstJobs.Select(x=> x.PlanId)
   .Intersect(reviewModel.lstPraudits.Select(y=> y.PlanId))
   .ToList();
```

> What I am doing wrong here

Your approach is wrong because `x.planId.Contains` will search substrings and you are passing a list to the method. It's the wrong approach anyway because you don't want to compare substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Using Intersect is a nice approach.. But if you say what you are doing wrong I would say you are iterating on the wrong thing. The query as per your appproach should be:

```
List<string> result = reviewModel.lstJobs.Select(x => reviewModel.lstPraudits.Select(y=>y.PlanId).Contains(x.planId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where` to compare between both List.

```
List<string> result =
         reviewModel.Where(x => x.planId.Contains(reviewModel.lstPraudits.Select(y=>y.PlanId)))
         .ToList();
```